# Arrange string by character placement in all possible ways

Tags: php, string

Lets say that I have a an alphanumeric sting

```
$string = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz012345678';
```

The characters in the above string could be arranged in a many number of ways simply by switch the placement of two or more of them.

I can't seem to find a mathematical way to write all of the possible ways in which a given collection of string can be arranged.

I started off with this:

```
<?php
     //Get the length of the string
     $length = strlen($string);

     //Create an empty array that will store each character
     $chars = array();

     for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++) {
         //Get each letter
         $part = substr($string, $i, 1);
         array_push($chars, $part);
     }

     for($i=0;$i<count($chars);$i++) {
         $current = $chars[$i];


     }
```

I'm having writers block solving this dilemma. Seems so easy to visualize but I can't seem to represent it in the text editor.

Comment: What's the end result you're after? The nr of combinations for a given string?

Comment: Are you trying to get all the possible outputs or are you trying to calculate the number of possible outcomes?

Comment: I'm trying to get all of the possible outputs

Comment: You will very soon reach astronomic numbers as the nr of combinations are calculated !n...so collecting them and outputting them seems impossible for even remotely long strings...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the logic for that.
Reference [Permutate a string](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-print-all-permutations-of-a-given-string/)

```
<?php
    function allString($string, $initial, $length){

        if($initial == $length){
            echo $string. "</br>";
        }else{
            for ($next=$initial; $next < $length ; $next++) { 
                swap($string, $initial, $next);
                allString($string, $initial+1, $length);    
                swap($string, $initial, $next);// backtrack
            }
        }
    }
    function swap(&$string, $initial, $next){
        $temp = $string[$initial];
        $string[$initial] = $string[$next];
        $string[$next] = $temp;
    }
    $string = "ABC";
    allString($string, 0, strlen($string));
?>
```

This illustrate the permutation of the string. It is using the **Backtrack Method**. I think you're looking for the same.

Comment: That's really interesting. Clears a lot up. Let's say that I wanted find out the number of times that all of those characters could be used (over again if needed) to populate a string that is 8 characters long. How would that be done?

Comment: @Lance can you tell me the number sequence will be same always means in a sequence of 012345678... or something else ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to ask me. But, this formula assumes that that length of the possible combos must be the length of the string. Let's that that each character in an 8 character string can be  either `A`, `B`, or `C`

Comment: @Lance You can remove the integer part from the string and then calculate the length. then Iterate over or vice versa

Comment: What integer part from the string? the `$initial+1`?

Comment: @Lance `$str = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz012345678';
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);` this will output `012345678` count the length of the `$matches` then iterate the loop. I should not write the whole answer for you. :P